# What is the best way to combine a suspend function and flow function where the suspend function might fail?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have two different functions I want to combine into one method:

Interface (repository):

```
suspend fun doSomeAction(id: String): Response
fun subscribeToResultFromAction(id: String): Flow<SomeResult>
```

Today I have the implementation which works but I don't like:

```
override fun execute(id: String): Flow<Response> {

        CoroutineScope(dispatcher).launch {
            repository.doSomeAction(id)
        }

        return repository.subscribeToResultFromAction(id).map { action ->

            when (action.name) {
                "NameA" -> Response(action.id, ....)
                "NameB" -> Response(action.id, ....)
                else -> {
                    Timber.e("Unexpected action!")
                    throw java.lang.Exception()
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

But I would like to set up the subscription first, so I don't miss out on any actions from doSomeAction(...). It can start producing results that I want to subscribe to before the subscription is ready, that's why I want to set up the subscription first. And if that suspend function fails there won't be anything to subscribe to. Should I then you throw some exception from it or can I silently and nicely end the terminate the flow?

`subscribeToResultFromAction()` won't get any results if `doSomeAction()` isn't successful.

```
override fun execute(id: String): Flow<Response> {


        return repository.subscribeToResultFromAction(id)
           .onStart { 
                repository.doSomeAction(id)
    
                // potentially handle failure here from doSomeAction()
                // or handle it differently than in the start of the flow? 

 
            }
           .map { action ->

            when (action.name) {
                "NameA" -> Response(action.id, ....)
                "NameB" -> Response(action.id, ....)
                else -> {
                    Timber.e("Unexpected action!")
                    throw java.lang.Exception()
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `flow { }` builder for this. Your suspend function that starts things off can be a part of the flow.

```
override fun execute(id: String): Flow<Response> = flow {
    try { 
        repository.doSomeAction(id)
    } catch (e: SomeException) {
        // Log something?
        return@flow // End the flow early
    }
    repository.subscribeToResultFromAction(id)
       .map { action ->

            when (action.name) {
                "NameA" -> Response(action.id, ....)
                "NameB" -> Response(action.id, ....)
                else -> {
                    Timber.e("Unexpected action!")
                    throw java.lang.Exception()
                }
            }

       }
       .let(::emitAll)
}
```

Another option instead of rethrowing your exception or silently ending the flow would be to make this Flow's type be a sealed interface that can wrap either the items or a failure state. Then the collector can check the type and react accordingly.

Comment: The problem is that I need to start subscribing to results before calling doSomeAction since doSomeAction triggers asynchronous events back that might start producing these events (that subscribeToResultFromAction wanna listen to) before subscribeToResultFromAction has a chance to set up the subscription if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is issue in your design,  your function doSomeAction(id) should return flow instead of separate function for flow subscription

you can do like this

class Repo {

```
fun doSomeAction(id) : Flow<Result>{

  return flow {
                 try{
                  val result = getDatafromServer(id)
                  emit(Result.Suceess(result)
                 }catch(e:Exception){
                   emit(Result.Error(e.message)
                 }

            }.stateIn(Dispatchers.IO)

 }
```

}

for error handling sealed class can be created and wrap the result in the same.

```
sealed class Result<out T> {
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error(val message: String) : Result<Nothing>()
}
```

Comment: Not really what I want to achieve.